# Calculating the modulus of large hexadecimal numbers without overflow

Tags: python, sage

I'm trying to do some cryptography questions for signatures, but my values are hexadecimal and they're too high to be calculated on SageMaths without overflow in both python and sage. How would i get around this? My attempted sage code is below.

Trying it in python and sage

```
N = ZZ(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, 16)

D = ZZ(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, 16)

M = ZZ(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, 16)

Z = M^D

SIG = mod(Z, N)

print(SIG)
```

---

> OverflowError: exponent must be at most 9223372036854775807

Answer (score 1):

The `pow` function from Python pretends to compute it:

```
>>> hex(pow(M, D, N))
'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'
```

Comment: Considering this is for one of my assignments, would this be feasible method when I need to verify signatures against a message too?

Comment: I have not controled whether the result is correct or not. I just looked at the builtin functions and was rather amazed to read that `pow` accepted a modulus argument.

Comment: Yes, you can use `pow` or `power_mod`.